# How to find a carriage return without a line feed after it with regex pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find a carriage return (\r) that doesn't have a line feed (\n) directly after it how would I do this with a regex pattern?

Comment: I'd recommend this tool for creating and debugging regular expressions: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 11):

What about the following regex with a negative lookahead:

```
\r(?!\n)
```

Comment: It'd need a multiline flag too

Comment: This just ate up everything. I'm doing a regex.replace(input, new input); and i used that as the pattern

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
 Regex.Match("\rtext\r\ntext.", "\r[^\n]", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```